# Host website with Node Express not work with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: node.js, express, windows-task-scheduler

I write a simple website, and host it with `Node Express`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('./'))
app.listen(7100, () => {
    console.log('started')
})
```

While putting it on server, I want it to be started whenever server restarts. So, I write one bat script and configre a windows task scheduler to run the bat script when server restarts. Here is the bat file conten.

```
node server.js
```

But it seems that windows task scheduler never start this node express server. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sufficiently confident that's enough for your batch file.  Don't you actually need to start it in the same directory as server.js?

Comment: There's "never starts the express server" and "never runes the .bat file", so before anything: find out which of those two it is by looking at your windows task event log? Because node needs to run scripts "in some directory", so if your .bat file doesn't first `cd` to the correct dir, it's almost certainly running the bat file, but there is no `server.js` in whatever dir it runs it in.

Comment: @ewokx, yes, your are correct. I totaly forget that I need to switch to my working directy firstly in that bat script. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node needs to actually find the js file and Windows Task Scheduler won't have any information on that.

So the easiest would be to put the following in your bat file:

```
@echo off
cd <full path which stores the server.js file>
node server.js
```